# Typescript - Type changes to string in for loop for array

Tags: typescript, types

I have declared a for loop on an array of a specific type. When I use this array in for loop, I get error because typescript detects it as type of string rather than the type of specific item as declared.

```js
const repos: Repo[] = config.get("repos");
for(const repo in repos) {
  calculate(repo)
}
```

I get error that the value that I am passing to calculate is not of type Repo, but of type string.

*NOTE: This is not a runtime error. I get it when in VS Code with code ts(2345)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely meant to use a `for ... of` loop, not a `for ... in` loop. The code you've written loops over the enumerable keys of an object, so repo will start off as the string `"0"`, then `"1"`, etc. If instead you do `for ... of`, you'll iterate through the array with repo being assigned the values in the array.

```
for(const repo of repos) {
  calculate(repo)
}
```